# Forgot baggage at Dubai. How to get it to Los Angeles?

Tags: luggage, dubai, los-angeles, dxb, lost-luggage

Last week, I travelled via Dubai to Los Angeles. During the security checking at Dubai Airport, I was asked to remove my laptop from my bag and after that I forgot to to take it back. i realised that only after I reached Los Angeles.

What is the best way I can get it to Los Angeles now. I called Dubai lost and found and they have identified the laptop there.

Comment: Did you ask them if they could mail it to you?

Comment: yes, they don't do that

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally after almost a couple of weeks, the laptop reached LAX.

What to do is simple, and here are the steps eliminating all the places I called unnecessarily.

1. Call the Dubai Lost and Found department. Give them as much details of the item as possible. Having an airlines tag certainly helped.
2. Once they located the item, you will be given a file reference number.
3. Call the airlines missed baggage handling number at the destination (LAX in my case). Give them the file reference number and the details of the item. Tell them to send a mail to Dubai lost and found department asking them to forward it to LAX.
4. Once Dubai receives the email, they will ship the item in the next available flight.
5. Collect it from the destination airport. (Going to do that this Saturday, keeping my fingers crossed that they shipped the correct item).

The biggest challenge was getting the numbers and once you get the numbers, getting a person to speak to. It was very difficult to find out the numbers online... like a treasure hunt game where I call one place to get the details for the next place.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to handling the matter yourself depending on if you paid via a credit card, most of the major vendors include Lost Baggage insurance at no additional cost if you pay for your tickets with the card. I personally haven't used the protection myself as I don't fly often, but I've heard AmEx is top notch with assistance, and Visa also does a good job.

MasterCard (which is what I've used for years) I've found is pretty good overall for benefits, although they typically are a bit more limited than AmEx & Visa.

It probably isn't necessary now since your items have been found, but sometimes it helps to have someone backing you up when it comes to international departments.